# TypeError: this.state.champions.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pulling data through an `API` on the back end than on the front end I'm pulling it from my server which I should be pushing to state in an empty array so i can map but I keep getting a

> TypeError: this.state.champions.map is not a function

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
class Champions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      champions: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get("/api/Champions").then(response => {
      this.setState({ champions: response.data });
      // console.log(response);
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.champions);
    // let champions = this.state.champions;
    let champList = this.state.champions.map((elem, ind) => {
      return <div key={elem} className="champCard" />;
    });
    return <div className="App">{champList}</div>;
  }
}

export default Champions;
```

[my console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfYyd.png)

Comment: Show what your console.log(this.state.champions) outputs.

Comment: response.data is probably not an array

Comment: You need to put the API call inside a `componentDidMount`, Inside `componentWillMount` an asynchronous call to fetch data will not return before the render happens. This means the component will render with empty data at least once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive an object in your `response.data` instead of an array.

So you can transform it to an array of champions like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  axios.get("/api/Champions").then(response => {
    this.setState({ champions: Object.values(response.data) });
  });
}
```

**Update:**

As it was suggested in comments - it's better to use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` in such case. Please read more about [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)